# How to convert bootstrap navbar to tabs using angular-ui?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to convert bootstrap nav to tabs using angular-ui bootstrap, is there any way to make this change with minimal code change. I looked at angular-ui documentation but it looks like i would not be able implement with ui-router. Any idea ?

main.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div >
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.dit">DIT</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.st">ST</a>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.uat">UAT</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a>PROD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngFileSaver',
        'btford.socket-io',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngSanitize',
        'timer'

    ]).config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            'use strict'
            /*
             * This has to be here because the browsers will not catch the home
             * state without it
             */
            //$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/);
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
                var $state = $injector.get('$state');
                $state.go('app.dit');
            });

            $stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'web/global/main.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.dit', {
                    url: '/dit',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
                    controller: 'DitCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.st', {
                    url: '/st',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/st.html',
                    controller: 'StCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.uat', {
                    url: '/uat',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/uat.html',
                    controller: 'UatCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.prod', {
                    url: '/prod',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/prod.html',
                    controller: 'ProdCtrl',
                });
```

Comment: This wouldn't meet your request of 'minimal code change', but you may want to check out the `uib-tabset` directive it should work OK with `ui-router` (I use Angular 1.5). https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: i tried with uib but its not loading data for states from their specify controllers.

Comment: why don't you just style them as tabs and leave the routing functionality the same. Not difficult to change the markup for the navbar itself

Comment: @charlietfl yes i can do that i just want look and feel as tabs, can you give me some example how  i would change styling for navs ?

Comment: copy the html structure from demo and use that instead of `navbar` ... nothing complicated about it